# getContentText で取得したデータとブラウザの検証から取得したデータが異なる

Tags: google-apps-script

```js
var url = 'https://Webページ';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var html = response.getContentText();
```

Google Apps Script で上記のようにして取得した HTML のデータ  間のコードと、Google Chrome の検証から要素をコピーして見比べるとデータに違いがありました。

具体的に言いますと、ある通販サイトで 58 点あるう商品のうち、上から 42 点までしか読み込めませんでした。Google Apps Script で取得したデータには、そもそも残りの 16 点のコードが存在していませんでした。

ブラウザ上で明らかに見えていて、要素を検証でも確認できるにも関わらず、getContentText で異なるコーディングのデータが取得されるのは、どのような理由からなのでしょうか。

Comment: 原因として2つ考えられて、1つ目は既に回答が付いていますが、クライアントサイド(JavaScript)で動的に追加されたパターンです。2つ目はサイトにレコメンドシステムなどが導入されていて、ユーザー(ブラウザのCookieなど)によって商品が出し分けられている場合です。この場合、ブラウザとGASで全く同じ値のCookieを送出してアクセスするなどしないと別のユーザーと判別され、同じ表示にならない可能性があります。

Comment: いずれにしても「ある通販サイト」のそのページのURLを質問に記載して頂かない限り、原因を想像するしかありません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ブラウザ上で明らかに見えていて、要素を検証でも確認できるにも関わらず、getContentText で異なるコーディングのデータが取得されるのは、どのような理由からなのでしょうか。

今回の現象と同じかはわかりませんが、
クライアントサイドスクリプトと連携して表示を行うページの場合は、このような現象が発生すると思います。

例えば、以下のように
サーバーサイドで生成された静的な商品データ表示と、ページを表示してからのクライアントサイドによる動的な商品データ表示を組み合わせたページなどです。
想像ですが、`UrlFetchApp.fetch`はページ内のjavascriptの実行までは行わないと思いますので、`response.getContentText()`で取得したHTML内には、商品1〜5の情報しか記載されていないと思います。

```
<ul class="items">
  <!-- サーバーサイドで生成 -->
  <li>商品1/li>
  <li>商品2/li>
  <li>商品3/li>
  <li>商品4/li>
  <li>商品5/li>
</ul>

<script>
 // ページがロードされてから
 // itemsに残りの商品情報サーバーから取得し商品6〜10を追加
</script>
```

Comment: なるほど、おっしゃるように Javascript による動的なページによるものが原因かと思われます。Phantom Js Cloud という外部ツールを使えば、一日に500ページ程度まで、実行後の HTML を取得できるようです。こういった外部ツールを用いない場合は、Google Apps Script で Javascript 実行後のページを取得することは難しいのでしょうか。

Comment: Google Apps Script の `UrlFetchApp.fetch`だけでは難しいと思います。